# Different delta rules

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am having a lot of troubles to understand this concept about delta rule. 
As far as I know, delta rule is used for updating weights during learning the network. 
Lets say I have these two formulas:

- [first formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Er2m.png)
- [second formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ask7c.png)

The first formula says exactly what? The new weight should be counted as:

```
learning rate (eta) * gradient of loss function.
```

This result will be new weight. Am i correct?

The second formula is confusing. What does it exactly say? Both should be delta rules, but what is the difference between them? Could you please explain me, what following parts of the formula are?
I think it is like that (but i am not totally sure with something...)

```
change weight between neuron ij = learning rate (eta) * (I dont have any idea what is gamai(t) - it is an output?) * xj (= i belive it is input of the neuron jx) + (momento (that is ok) * wij(t-1) = i think it is previous weight).
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

[Delta rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule) is a gradient descent algorithm.
The two formulas you've given give you the gradient of the weights to perform the gradient descent, not the new weights.

The first formula is a general expression while the second is a rule on how to compute the gradient coefficient in function of the previous gradient.

The new weights are computed as in every gradient descent algorithm:

```
w_new = w - lamda*dw
```

where lambda is a positive number that may be constant or depend on the number of the iteration.

Comment: hm, so how does it work all together with these formulas? I can count loss function as (derivative E/derivative wij) and now when i want to update weights in all layers, how will it work? Which formula of these two will i use? And what means "dw" in your formula, please? i am totally confused :/

Comment: `dw` is the gradient of the weights, it is merely the same as the the left member of the first equation (they included the lambda coefficient of the gradient descent formula).
So if you can compute the left member of the equation, your new weights are computed as the previous weight minus the left member of the equations. Check out the wikipedia page, they explain the details of the formula(s). Is that clear enough?